# Node.js headless browser replacement for PhantomJS for jasmine tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, jasmine, phantomjs, headless-browser

PhantomJS development is suspended, so I need to find replacement for it.
In my Ruby on Rails application Javascript Unit tests are running via jasmine-gem and they run in PhantomJS headless browser.
Could you please advise alternatives for PhantomJS and ways how to incorporate them to run jasmine tests?

Comment: It's off-topic question. Any way, Nightmare or headless Chrome (Puppeteer). It's unclear what this has to do with Jasmine because it's primarily intended for unit tests. For instance, Testcafe is intended for E2E and supports Chrome natively.

Comment: Definitely puppeteer